# maximum likelihood for the exponential distribution

Tags: exponential-distribution

I found this question on a past exam and i wanted to know if my solution is correct!
I apologize if it's not 100% clear but i'm translating it from italian and it's already written in a really bad form to begin with.
Let's suppose that 10 rats are used in a biomedic study. Each of them is injected with poison and after that, they're injected with a serum that is supposed to increase their life duration. The life duration of the 10  rats (in months) is 14, 17, 27, 18,12, 8, 22, 13, 19 e 12. Let's suppose that we use an exponential distribution, calculate the maximum likelihood of the average life duration.
This is my solution in matlab:

A = [14, 17, 27, 18,12, 8, 22, 13, 19, 12];

n = 10;

lambda = n/sum(A);

rats = zeros(10);

for i=1:n

```
rats(i) = lambda*exp(-lambda*A(i));
```

end

Comment: Since the question expects a single time answer and your `lambda` is something like a rate while your `rats(i)` gives ten likelihoods, that is presumably not the solution

Comment: You should be looking for the $\beta$ which maximises $\prod_i \frac1\beta e^{-x_i/\beta}$

Answer (score 2):

The pdf of an exponential distribution is
$$
f_X(x;\lambda) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}
$$
for $x \ge 0$.

Supposing (life duration) data $x_n$ as independent realization,
the likelihood writes
$$
l(\lambda)=
\prod_n f_X(x_n;\lambda)
$$

The ML estimator of $\lambda$ minimizes the NLL (negative log likelihood)
$$
\phi(\lambda)=
\lambda \sum_n x_n - N \log \lambda
$$
Computing the derivative yields
$$
\phi'(\lambda)=
\sum_n x_n - \frac{N}{\lambda}
$$
from which
$$
\frac{1}{\lambda_{ML}}
=
\frac{1}{N} \sum_n x_n
$$
The RHS is the maximum likelihood of the average life duration.